# When can a statement in Second Order Logic be converted into a statement in First Order Logic

Tags: first-order-logic, peano-axioms, second-order-logic

I was reading on first and second order logic (The first has quantifiers over individuals of the domain and the second can have quantifiers over predicates as well - see this question: [Differentiating First/Second order logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2483821/differentiating-first-second-order-logic)) and saw these two wikepdia pages:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_logic#Non-reducibility_to_first-order_logic-> With a section about how you can't convert the least upper bound property of the real numbers into FOL.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic -> With a section on how to axiomative the induction axiom of Peano Arithmetic (a statement in SOL) into a FOL axiom schema.

So it seems that sometimes you can convert sentences in SOL into FOL and sometimes not. Is there a result that tells you when this conversion is possible?

My background is introductory courses to logics and set theory and a chapter on Recursive functions, from the book "Logic and Complexity" by Richard Lassaigne.

Thanks in advance

Comment: A FOL axiom-schema is the way to overcome the syntactical limitations of FOL: impossibility to quantify the predicate. But the solution is not equivalent to the SOL one. With SOL version of PA a quantifier on a predicate has as domain all subsets of $\mathbb N$, that are uncountable many.

Comment: An axiom-schema in FOL, instead, has only countable many instances, because we may instantiate the schema with formulas, and formulas of the language are countable.

Comment: Then what is meant with the sentence in the wikipedia page: "(...)it can be transformed into a first-order axiom schema of induction". What does tranformed mean? Is an FOL schema always weaker than SOL statement? Thanks